# Simulate a specific page when making AJAX calls

Tags: ajax

I'm interested in loading parts of the interface of our theme over AJAX and wrote a function to handle generic functions. (Code below.)

It works fine, but wp_nav_menu(), when run through this function, doesn't reliably mark links with appropriate classes like "current-menu-item". It works maybe half of the time.

Do you know why this would be? Do any functions / global variables need to be handled that query_posts() won't take care of?

```
add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_ananda_ajax', 'ananda_ajax_output' );
add_action( 'wp_ajax_ananda_ajax', 'ananda_ajax_output' );

function ananda_ajax_output() {

global $post;

$function   = $_POST['function'];
$parameters = $_POST['parameters'];
$post_id    = $_POST['post_id'];

if ( $post_id && ananda_ajax_is_approved_function( $function ) ) {

    // Query
    query_posts( array( 'p' => $post_id, 'post_type' => 'any' ) );

    // Output the HTML
    ob_start();

    if ( have_posts() ) {

            the_post();

            if ( $parameters ) {
                call_user_func_array( $function, $parameters );
            } else {
                call_user_func( $function );
            }

    } else {
        // No posts
    }

    // Restore original post data. Probably not needed, but standard best practice.
    wp_reset_postdata();

    // Send the output
    $output = ob_get_clean();
    echo $output;

}

wp_die(); // Standard AJAX callback procedure

}
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue turned out to be elsewhere. But I did learn that there is no way to overwrite the queried URL directly, as it comes from $_SERVER variables.

The answer here had some code for anyone who wants to do that:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10739721/wordpress-ajax-parse-url